# Change variable name on each iteration in for loop MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have large array `P` which is changing size and values in each iteration. I need to be able to change the title of my output array to match the given iteration, i.e. for bin 1.4 I would like output to be p1.4 or p14.

Can anyone help?

```
for bin = 1:0.1:2;
    rows = find(DAT(:,27) > bin);
    p{bin} = DAT(rows,:);
end
```

Comment: `fprintf('p%.1f\n', bin);` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the code is

```
for bin = 1:0.1:2;
    rows = find(DAT(:,27) > bin);
    current_p = DAT(rows,:);
    eval(sprintf('p%0.f=current_p;', bin * 10));
end
```

But why do you need this? Consider use a smarter container like containers.Map:

```
p = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'double')    
for bin = 1:0.1:2
     rows = find(DAT(:,27) > bin);
     p(bin) = DAT(rows,:);
end
disp(p(1.2))
```

It could be more convinient.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
bins = 1:0.1:2;
for ii = 1: numel(bins)
    bin = bins(ii);
    rows = find( DAT(:,27) > bin );
    p{ii} = DAT(rows,:);
end
```